# When I use realloc() my pointers inside the malloced table get lost

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

In the code below I try to find names-of-data stored inside a file that contain the given string and then print the names found outside of the function . Data inside the file is stored in the form of |NAME of DATA|NUM of BYTES of DATA|DATA|. The function receives as parameters the File Descriptor of the file ,the string we try to find inside of the names in the file and a struct that contains a table where the found names will be stored (** findNames) additionally with the size of that table .
The problem that I have is that when the function realloc is used to increase the size of the table ,pointers already stored there disappear .

The struct :

```
typedef struct{
    int size ;
    char **findNames ;
}findReturn;
```

The function :

```
int find(int *fd,char *namepart,findReturn *findResults){
    int i = 2 ;
    int j = 0;
    int dataSize ;
    int filesize ;
    char name[255];
    char **temp ;
    
    errno = 0 ;
    if(*fd == -1){
        return MISSING_DB ;
    }

    filesize = lseek(*fd,0,SEEK_END);
    lseek(*fd,2,SEEK_SET);
    while(i < filesize){
        read(*fd,name + j,1);
        i++ ;
        if(name[j] == '\0'){
            if(stringFinder(namepart,name) == SUCCESS){
                (findResults->size)++;
                temp = (char **)realloc(findResults->findNames,findResults->size);
                if(temp != NULL){
                    findResults->findNames = temp ;
                    findResults->findNames[findResults->size - 1] = 
                                (char*)malloc(strlen(name) * sizeof(char) + 1);
                    strcpy(findResults->findNames[findResults->size - 1],name);
                }
                else{
                   (findResults->size)--; 
                }
            }
            read(*fd,&dataSize,sizeof(int));
            i += sizeof(int) ;
            i += dataSize ;
            lseek(*fd,i,SEEK_SET);
            j = 0;
        }
        else{
            j++ ;    
        }
    }
    if(errno != 0){
        return FAIL ;
    }
    return SUCCESS ;
}
```

And its use in main:

```
case 'f':{
                scanf(" %s", namepart);
                returnValue = find(&databaseFd,namepart,&findResults) ;
                if(findResults.findNames != NULL){
                    printf("\n##\n");
                    for(i=0; i < findResults.size; i++){
                        printf("%s\n", findResults.findNames[i]);
                    }
                }
                else if(returnValue == MISSING_DB){
                    fprintf(stderr,"No open db file.\n");   
                }
                else if(returnValue == FAIL){
                    perror("\nUnexpected Error");
                    return 42 ;
                }
                break ;
```

Here is an example :

I launched the program and called the find function through main
giving a string that I want the function to find

```
f ile
```

The file in use has written inside :

```
00000000: 4442 6669 6c65 3100 0d00 0000 4865 6c6c  DBfile1.....Hell
00000010: 6f0a 576f 726c 6421 0a66 696c 6532 000d  o.World!.file2..
00000020: 0000 0048 656c 6c6f 0a57 6f72 6c64 210a  ...Hello.World!.
```

If file saved the names successfully then it should be printed in the final output :

```
##
file1
file2
```

But instead I get segmetation fault:

```
==4234==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00000000be30 (pc 0x000100faae10 bp 0x00016f22f220 sp 0x00016f22e960 T0)
==4234==The signal is caused by a UNKNOWN memory access.
    #0 0x100faae10 in __sanitizer::internal_strlen(char const*)+0x4 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x56e10)
    #1 0x100f72034 in wrap_printf+0x8c (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x1e034)
    #2 0x100bd3360 in main project3.c:57
    #3 0x193ce7f24  (<unknown module>)
```

During execution (through debugger):

First name is saved at the right position

```
(lldb) p findResults->findNames[0]
(char *) $2 = 0x0000000102300710 "file1"
```

After realloc :

In the temporary pointer

```
(lldb) p temp[0]
(char *) $5 = 0x000000000000be10 ""
```

And then on the main table

```
(lldb) p findResults->findNames[0]
(char *) $6 = 0x000000000000be10 ""
```

Comment: The `realloc` call is not allocating enough bytes. It should be `realloc(findResults->findNames,findResults->size*sizeof(char*))` or `realloc(findResults->findNames,findResults->size*sizeof(*findResults->findNames))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One immediately obvious problem is that the `realloc` call to reallocate `findResults->findNames` is allocating the wrong size of memory. It is allocating one byte per element, but be allocating the number of elements multiplied by the size of each element. The size of each element can be expressed as `sizeof(char *)` or `sizeof(*findResults->findNames)` or `sizeof(findResults->findNames[0])`. `realloc` returns a `void *`. There is no need to cast the result to a different pointer type in C.

```
            temp = realloc(findResults->findNames,findResults->size*sizeof(*findResults->findNames));
```

If `findResults->findNames` is pointing to memory allocated by `malloc` elsewhere in the code, that also needs to be the correct size.

Although the code correctly checks the `realloc` call for success, it does not check the subsequent `malloc` call. I suggest only incrementing `findResults->size` if both the `realloc` and the `malloc` calls are successful:

```
            if(stringFinder(namepart,name) == SUCCESS){
                temp = realloc(findResults->findNames,
                               (findResults->size + 1) * sizeof(char*));
                if(temp != NULL){
                    findResults->findNames = temp ;
                    findResults->findNames[findResults->size] = 
                                malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
                    if (findResults->findNames[findResults->size] != NULL){
                        strcpy(findResults->findNames[findResults->size],name);
                        findResults->size++; 
                    }
                }
            }
```